# Pycharm "Optimize imports" causes error in project

Tags: python, pycharm

My simplified folder structre:

```
/lights
/lights/__init__.py
/lights/light.py
/lights/directional_light.py
main.py
```

I have a python package named lights, in `\__init__.py`, I import classes like this:

```
from .light import Light
from .directional_light import DirectionalLight
from .spot_light import SpotLight
```

so I can do from lights import * in main.py

`DirectionalLight` inherits from Light so I import Light there too like this:

`from lights import Light`

Everything works.

BUT
When I use "optimize imports" of Pycharm, it changes to

```
from .directional_light import DirectionalLight
from .light import Light
from .spot_light import SpotLight
```

And I get an error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'Light' from 'lights'`

Because first, it goes to directional_light.py and tries to import from light import Light which is not imported in `\__init__.py` yet.

I wonder why Pycharm changes the order and breaks stuff. Is it just ordering alphabetically?

This makes me question the imports I do. 
Any comments and suggestions?

Comment: You can disable sorting in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | Python | Imports**. Btw not sure how good is the idea to rely on the import order so heavily.